# How should I interpret a null result of $stmt->execute();?

Tags: php, debugging

I run a query that worked recently, then changes were made to the DB and I have to update the prepared statement.

Also, I use a log function to keep track of what's going on.

The instructions I perform are:

```
...
$result = $stmt->execute();
my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: " . $result);
```

The result of the log function (see only the middle row) is:

```
[2018-04-23 05:04:23] [Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] FacePngBase64: ./images/faces/x9oijohlfzeesj6apjqshokfn0eyad2y.png
[2018-04-23 05:04:23] [Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: 
[2018-04-23 05:04:23] [Database.php].[storePost] Saving the images.
```

Apparently it's null, I do not understand why. It should be true or false. Quite right?

Among other things, all the previous queries (there are many other x in addition to the one I posted) work and update the database, but not this.

I would like to understand what the error is and where it is. It's still a good point to find out which query is not working.

In any case, the question remains the same: why does that statement (`$stmt->execute();`) returns null?

---

> Update I post here the full function:
>   As asked by [ibrahim-hafiji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582480/ibrahim-hafiji) I post the full function below:

```
public function insertPlayerDevice($UidDevice, $Action, $Locale, $Language, $Name, $Age, $Sex, $Avatar, $Costume, $Level, $MovementsPoints, $Score, $CardPngBase64, $FacePngBase64)
{
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Adding info to the PlayerDevice table.");
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Adding following fields:");
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] UidDevice: " . $UidDevice);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Action: " . $Action);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Locale: " . $Locale);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Language: " . $Language);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Name: " . $Name);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Age: " . $Age);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Sex: " . $Sex);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Avatar: " . $Avatar);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Costume: " . $Costume);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Level: " . $Level);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] Score: " . $Score);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] CardPngBase64: " . $CardPngBase64);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] FacePngBase64: " . $FacePngBase64);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO PlayerDevice(UidDevice, Action, Locale, Language, Name, Age, Sex, Avatar, Costume, Level, MovementsPoints, Score, CardPngBase64, FacePngBase64) VALUES (:UidDevice, :Action, :Locale, :Language, :Name, :Age, :Sex, :Avatar, :Costume, :Level, :MovementsPoints, :Score, :CardPngBase64, :FacePngBase64)";
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':UidDevice',$UidDevice , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Action',$Action , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Locale',$Locale , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Language',$Language , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Name',$Name , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Age',$Age , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Sex',$Sex , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Avatar',$Avatar , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Costume',$Costume , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Level',$Level , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':MovementsPoints',$MovementsPoints , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Score',$Score , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':CardPngBase64',$CardPngBase64 , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':FacePngBase64',$FacePngBase64 , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: " . $result);

}
```

However, I would like to point out that this query before the database was changed was working correctly.

---

> Problem solved:

I thank everyone for their advice and help.

I summarize here directly how much it has been useful for me to be able to help someone who could have my same problems.

My mistake was that I assumed to see `false` or`true` printed in the log file, but if it is false, it returns an empty string. PHP is like that.

To find prepared statement errors you can use `$ result-> errorInfo ();` as in the code below:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->errorInfo();
    ob_start();
    var_dump($result);
    my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: " .ob_get_clean());
```

Thanks to this, I immediately identified the error in the Database:

```
[2018-04-23 06:04:44] [Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "42S22"
  [1]=>
  int(1054)
  [2]=>
  string(36) "Unknown column 'Sex' in 'field list'"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: Why you assume its null?

Comment: As being told that either your query failed to compile or you passed incorrect params to the execute

Comment: I assumed it's null because the my_log function does not print me neither true nor false.

Comment: If you have not set PDO to use exceptions then output the real error message using `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());`

Comment: @kitsune `true` casted to string gives `1`, `false` gives empty string, check my answer

Comment: @kitsune If you run this query out of the function, does it work?

Comment: 'then changes were made to the DB' if we knew what the changes were it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

[execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns boolean, in your case it will be `false`, `false` casted to string gives empty string. That's why after "result:" there is nothing more.

To get more readable output you can replace your log line to

```
my_log("[Database.php].[insertPlayerDevice] SQL prepared statement result: " . ($result?"true":"false"));
```

To check why it's failing use [errorInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).